# Will a soft shutdown turn LED off when connected to power?

Tags: gpio, python, power, led

My project involves turning on/off a LED respective to the Pi's on/off state.

Connecting a LED to the power pins 1 and 6 (3.3v and GND) this will light up the LED when the Pi is running and the LED will be off when the Pi is completely shut down. Similarly, you can connect the LED to a digital output and control it through software.

My general question is - if connected to pin 1 and 6 and the Pi is commanded to halt or soft shut-down, will the LED go off?

Comment: Why not try it? The Pi is a tool for learning/experimentation. (The answer is no, pin 1 is a power pin.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3V3 pin (pin 1) and the ground pin (pin 6) are permanently powered while power is available at the microUSB or expansion header power pins.

So the answer is no.